# Make particles spawn continuously with Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working on a school project with pygame and the main objectives is to make a lot of objects appear and move randomly. So I wanted to make some particles spawn and move randomly and I came up with this.

```
import pygame, random

# -- Variables --

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps_limit = 60.0

resx = 1600 
resy = 900
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([resx,resy])

# -- Classes --

class Particule():
    def __init__ (self,color,radius):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.color = color
        self.radius = radius
        self.position_x = resx/2
        self.position_y = resy/2

    def update(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, (self.position_x,self.position_y),self.radius)

    def random_movement(self):
        self.position_x += random.randint(0,10)
        self.position_y -= random.randint(0,5)

    def life(self):
        self.radius -= 1

# -- Objects --

particule1 = Particule((255,0,0),100)


# -- Game loop --

running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(fps_limit)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.fill((0,0,0))

    particule1.update()
    particule1.random_movement()
    particule1.life()

    pygame.display.set_caption("Baguette")

    pygame.display.flip()   
pygame.quit()
```

I tried doing some while/if/for loops but only one object appears and then none

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Comment: Yes everything is in order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crate a list for the particles:

```py
particles = []
```

Use [`pygame.time.get_ticks()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) to get number of milliseconds since [`pygame.init()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.init) was called. Define the time at which the 1st particle must appear. If the time exceeds create a particle and set the time for the next particle to be created:

```py
next_particle_time = 0

running = True
while running:
    # [...]

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    if current_time > next_particle_time:
        particles.append(Particule((255,0,0), 100))         
        next_particle_time = current_time + 200    # 0.2 second interval
```

Draw and move all the particle in a loop:

```py
running = True
while running:
    # [...]

    for p in particles[:]:
        p.update()
        p.random_movement()
        p.life()
        if p.radius < 1:
            particles.remove(p)
```

---

Complete example

```py
import pygame, random

# -- Variables --
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps_limit = 60.0
resx = 1600 
resy = 900
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([resx,resy])
pygame.display.set_caption("Baguette")

# -- Classes --
class Particule():
    def __init__ (self,color,radius):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.color = color
        self.radius = radius
        self.position_x = random.randint(radius, 1600-radius)
        self.position_y = random.randint(radius, 900-radius)

    def update(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, (self.position_x,self.position_y),self.radius)

    def random_movement(self):
        self.position_x += random.randint(-10,10)
        self.position_y -= random.randint(-5,5)

    def life(self):
        self.radius -= 1

# -- Objects --
particles = []
next_particle_time = 0

# -- Game loop --
running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(fps_limit)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    if current_time > next_particle_time:
        particles.append(Particule((255,0,0), 100))         
        next_particle_time = current_time + 200 # 0.2 second interval

    screen.fill((0,0,0))

    for p in particles[:]:
        p.update()
        p.random_movement()
        p.life()
        if p.radius < 1:
            particles.remove(p)
    print(len(particles))

    pygame.display.flip()   

pygame.quit()
```